# SQL table 1 colume to table 2 two columes relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables.

Table 1:

```
ID  |  Statecode
---------------------
1   |  VA
2   |  TX
```

Table 2:

```
b_state |  m_state
------------------
2       |  1
1       |  2
```

I would like to write a query that will provide me result with the value like this:

Output:

```
bus_state |  mail_state
-----------------------
TX        |  VA
VA        |  TX
```

What join should I use to get the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join `Table 1` *twice* to `Table 2`:

```
SELECT b.Statecode AS bus_state, m.Statecode AS mail_state
FROM   `Table 2` t2
  JOIN `Table 1` b ON b.ID = t2.b_state
  JOIN `Table 1` m ON m.ID = t2.m_state
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ddfd/1/0).